# Please help me understand Javascript anonymous functions and jQuery .proxy()

Tags: javascript, jquery, anonymous-function

I've been trying to wrap my head around how javascript functions and scope work, and it just doesn't make sense to me. Can someone please explain why the following code outputs: 'animal says meow' instead of 'kitty says meow'?

```
(function($, exports){
  var animal = function(){};
  exports.Animal = animal;
})(jQuery, window);

(function($, Animal){
  var kitty = new Animal;
  kitty.sayHi = function(){
    console.log(this);
    console.log('says meow');
  }
  $($.proxy(function(){
    $('#js_test').click($.proxy(kitty.sayHi, kitty));
  }, kitty))
})(jQuery, Animal);
```

UPDATE

@FunkyFresh pointed out in the comments that console.log calls toString when it's passed an object, which by default returns the object's type (animal). When I update the above code with

```
animal.prototype.name = 'Mammal';
```

in the top block of code, and

```
kitty.name = 'Zax';
```

in the bottom, the console outputs 'Zax says meow', which seems about right.

Comment: The example shown on jQuery's site gives a pretty good comment break down, just follow the logic, it jumps around a lot. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/

Comment: This is the interview question from hell.

Comment: Interviewing a front end guy next week.  I think I will bust this out!  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @nums: does that imply you know the answer?  Please share :)

Comment: @RSG: I don't think it does; that's the sinister thing about it.

Comment: Can you link to a jsfiddle which exhibits the behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(function($) {})(jQuery)

in this code (function($){}) declares the function. Then (jQuery) imediately calls the function passing in the jQuery object.

so the first block of code passes in jQuery and the window object. Animal is added to the window object, which is the global scope.

in the second block a click event is added to an element and kitty.sayHi is passed in as the event handler. However if the event handler was not proxied then the this keyword in the eventhandler would return the element that has triggered the event. So by using the proxy the scope of the eventhandler becomes kitty.

I hope that is correct, this is new to me also.

Comment: This is hardly the time to hope to be correct. This answer needs and deserves a proper, educated response.

Comment: Yeah, that's how I follow the logic too. What trips me up at the end is that if the the scope of the eventhandler is 'kitty', why does it return 'animal'? It looks like .sayHi is now a method on animal, not just kitty.

Comment: ok i'm pretty sure it is correct. And my answer is clearly educated.

Comment: well animal = function(){}; is a constructor of an empty object. So Kitty's prototype.constructor is animal so it is of type animal basically. console.log expects a string so it calls toString on the animal object which by default returns it's type.. animal. I'd quite like to add a toString method the animal object that returns something different just to check though.

Comment: Hey, I think that's it! Instead of 'console.log(this)', I tried 'console.log(this.name)', and I assigned different values to animal.name and kitty.name. When I ran the code, it printed out kitty's name not animal's name.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** `kitty` is an *instance* of `Animal`. So it'll never say kitty. All those `proxy` wrappers are careful misdirections.

Lets see:

```
(function($, exports){
  var animal = function(){};
  exports.Animal = animal;
})(jQuery, window);
```

Just a disguise to say: `window.Animal = function(){};`

You're creating an anonymous function passing jQuery and window object to it and executing it immediately. This creates `Animal` class in `window` scope

---

Now jquery.proxy allows you to change the context of a function: `jQuery.proxy( functionName, context )` - so inside `functionName`, `this` refers to `context` (`this == context`).

`$.proxy(kitty.sayHi, kitty)` says call `sayHi` passing `kitty` as context.

Now `kitty = new Animal` (this is called a closure actaully since you're accessing parent function's variable), so `this` -> `Animal`

```
(function($, Animal){

  // create a new instance of Animal, assign it to local variable kitty
  var kitty = new Animal;

  // assign sayHi to kitty object
  kitty.sayHi = function(){
    console.log(this);
    console.log('says meow');
  }


  // $() shortcut that says run this code on DOM ready
  $($.proxy(function(){   
    // this proxy almost does nothing as we do not refer to this object insdie it

    // says on click of js_Test, call kitty.sayHi with context = kitty
    $('#js_test').click($.proxy(kitty.sayHi, kitty));

  }, kitty))

})(jQuery, Animal);
```

So when the click handler is called, its actually `Animal.sayHi`.

Comment: Actually if I take out that first proxy, which you said does almost nothing, the code doesn't work anymore. Any idea why that would be?

Comment: +1 for *"this proxy almost does nothing..."*. It would be a little more interesting if the inner `$.proxy` took advantage of the outer one by doing `$.proxy(this.sayHi, this)`.

Comment: @patrick dw: yep! But I think that would give it away a little more too... Having multiple kitty that do nothing is more confusing - do they do smothing, or not?

Comment: Good point. A little misdirection to keep you scratching your head.